# How to convert from any base to base 10 in Java

Tags: java

i'm new at Java. I want to write a program that converts from base 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 16 to base 10 using only aritmetic operations.

I've done with reading a string from keyboard (in case if number is in hexadecimal) and converting it to an integer, after this i made a while loop what split number to digits and inverts them.

Now i don't know how to make this digits to multiply with 2 at power 0, 1, 2, etc.(in binary case) to convert the number to base 10.

For example 1001 (number 9 in decimal) it's like 1x2(pow 0)+0x2(pow 1)+0x2(pow 2)+1x2(pow 3).

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Introduceti din ce baza doriti sa convertiti numarul: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 16 ");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduceti numarul care doriti sa fie convertit din baza aleasa ");
    String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
    if (n==2){
        int conv = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
        while (conv>0){
            System.out.println (conv%10);
            conv = conv/10;        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does all the IO have to to with the question?

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: It is very simple and you will learn more by trying to work it out yourself.  You just need a loop and one expression.  You don't need power of as that is just slower/more complex.

Comment: Ok, thanks for advice, i'll try to think and implement the code by myself ;)

Comment: `Scanner`, `BufferedReader`, and all the other IO classes have nothing to do with your question. Please edit your question to trim down your code to what is necessary to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Well, i need them to input the number from keyboard (in any base except base 10) and the output must be the decimal base.

Comment: user, that's irrelevant. What @LutzHorn is pointing out is that that part of the code has nothing to do with your direct question -- how to manipulate the base of numbers -- and only serves to distract those trying to understand your code and your problem. Better if you whittle down your posted code to the minimum necessary for the question itself, and for compilation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`Integer.toString(int i, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29):

```
int i = 1234567890;
for (int base : new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 16}) {
  String s = Integer.toString(i, base);
}
```

The reverse can be done with [`Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)):

```
String s = "010101";
for (int base : new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 16}) {
  Integer i = Integer.parseInt(s, base);
}
```

Comment: From any base to base 10, not from binary base to other bases

Comment: Still what? What is missing?

Comment: "using only aritmetic operations"

Comment: True, but why reinvent the wheel? Java includes the `Integer` class. So let's use it. Of course, if the question is homework and use of the JDK is forbidden by some weird teacher, the question is off-topic here in SO :)

Comment: Is a homework question off-topic ? Never heard that.

Comment: It is if the person asking the question does not show that he tried to solve the problem and is only asking SO for a solution.

Comment: That's different case

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
class Bases
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            //tests
        String l1 = "01010101"; //base 2, 85
        String l2 = "123123123"; // base 4, 112347
        String l3 = "FFFF"; //base 16, 65535

        System.out.println(rebase(l1,2));
        System.out.println(rebase(l2,4));
        System.out.println(rebase(l3,16));
    }

    //symbols array
    private static final String SYMBOLS = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    //actual algorithm 
    public static long rebase(String number, int base)
    {
        long result = 0;
        int position = number.length(); //we start from the last digit in a String (lowest value)
        for (char ch : number.toCharArray())
        {
            int value = SYMBOLS.indexOf(ch);
            result += value * pow(base,--position); //this is your 1x2(pow 0)+0x2(pow 1)+0x2(pow 2)+1x2(pow 3)

        }
        return result;
    }

    //power - don't know if this is needed?
    private static long pow(int value, int x)
    {
        if (x == 0) return 1;
        return value * pow(value,x-1);
    }
}
```

If this is your class assessment then you should spend some time in trying to understand the code. You can replace pow() function by a built-in Java function if this is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Consider an example,  
Convert (235) base 8 into base 10.

5 x 8^0 = 5  
3 x 8^1 = 24   
2 x 8^2 = 128   
Now simply add these values together.   
5 + 24 + 128 = 157  
Answer: (235)base 8 = (157)base 10  
For more example, refer [This URL][1]
```

http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Introduction/tobase10.htm

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.next(); //235
    int b = in.nextInt(); //8 
    int result = getBase10(s, b); //getBase10("235",8);
    System.out.println(result);
}    

private static int getBase10(String s, int b) {

    int base = 0, pow = 0;
    int[] a = new int[s.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        a[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0'; //Convert into int array
    }

    for (int i = a.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        base += a[i] * Math.pow(b,pow); //Generalised formula for conversion  
        pow++;  
    }
    System.out.println("Base 10 : "+base); // base = 157  
    return base; //157  
}
```

Comment: Gosh that's... ugly... Why two loops? Why an array?

Answer (score -2):

```
public class base2ToBase10Conversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input Base 2 value:");
        int a = input.nextInt();
        int b = a/10000000;
        double c = b* Math.pow(2, 7);
        int d = Math.abs(a-(10000000*b));
        int e = d/1000000;
        double f = e* Math.pow(2,6);
        int g = Math.abs(d-(1000000*e));
        int h = g/100000;
        double i = h * Math.pow(2,5);
        int j = Math.abs(g-(100000*h));
        int k = j/10000;
        double l = k * Math.pow(2,4);
        int m = Math.abs(j-(10000*k));
        int n = m/1000;
        double o = n * Math.pow(2, 3);
        int p = Math.abs(m-(1000*n));
        int q = p/100;
        double r = q* Math.pow(2, 2);
        int s = Math.abs(p-(100*q));
        int t = s/10;
        double u = t* Math.pow(2,1);
        int v = Math.abs(s-(10*t));

        double base10 = c + f + i + l + o + r + u + v;

        System.out.println("Valuse in Base 10: " + base10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not only does this not convert from **any base** as the question asked, but it doesn't even cover valid base 2 values like `100000001` (257)