# How to encrypt a string with another key?

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have a string than I want to encrypt to send it over an insecure channel.

I want to:

Convert to int `my-val` & `my-private-key`. Then, multiply both. Send it. When receiving it, divide by `my-private-key` converted as int and get `my-val`.

I tried to used `Integer.parseInt` and `Integer.toString` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19607058/10952503). It seems to work with `System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("Kona", 27));` (as Java's documentation said)

So I made this:

```
int base = 27;
String key = "some key";
String cmd = "some val";
int based = Integer.parseInt(cmd, base);
System.out.println("Based: " + based);
int crypted = based * Integer.parseInt(key, base);
System.out.println("Crypted: " + crypted);
// here use un-secure channel to send/receive
int received = crypted;
int back = received / Integer.parseInt(key, base);
System.out.println("Get back: " + back);
System.out.println("Final result: " + Integer.toString(back, base));
```

But I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "some val"` at the 4st line.

I tried with base 10, 16, 27, 32. Even if I understand why 10 & 16 doesn't work, why 27 & 32 don't ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: What number do you expect `Integer.parseInt("some val", 27)` to return?

Comment: All the characters in "Kona" are digits in base 27. The characters in "some val" are not. You can parse letters as digits in base 36 instead of 27 (if that's something like what you were trying to do), but that won't work for the space.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't know exactly, with the radix (with Kona in doc) it should return something

Comment: Should it? Definitely? How do you expect it to treat the space? What do you expect `Character.digit(' ', 27)` to return?

Comment: @JonSkeet 20 ? like %20 ? Different radix are here to make it works with all different chars. How do you think I should do ?

Comment: @Elikill58: Well %20 is indicating a decimal value of 32, just in hex... but what I'm suggesting to you is that you're asserting that `Integer.parseInt("some val", 27)` should return without throwing an exception, but that doesn't seem to be what the documentation says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking to encrypt with another string. I get the idea to multiply both, and so convert them into int. But, it seems to have informations lost with operation.

So, I searched for another way, and I found this one:

```java
private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final Key MY_KEY = new SecretKeySpec("16-char priv key".getBytes(), ALGORITHM);

private Cipher getCipher(int mode) throws Exception {
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(mode, MY_KEY);
    return c;
}

public String encrypt(String valueToEnc) throws Exception {
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(getCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE).doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes()));
}

public String decrypt(String encryptedValue) throws Exception {
    return new String(getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE).doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedValue)));
}
```

How it works ? It encrypt and decrypt with a key. This key should be a 16-chars one. Also, to make it easier to show/send/receive, it's converted into base 64.

Example of how to use:

```java
String myVal = "some val";
String encrypt = encrypt(myVal);
System.out.println("Encrypt: " + encrypt);
String decrypt = decrypt(encrypt);
System.out.println("Decrypt: " + decrypt);
```

Output:

```
Encrypt: ERJZ7ZOJcNpQEAvrb6wPOA==
Decrypt: some val
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on below wikipedia link of numeral system, Java will check each character of your input string against the range of radix parameter and if its not in range than it will throw exception.

Visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems,

Apart from that, Below is explanation from geeksforgeek site.

- The string is null or of zero-length
- The value represented by the string is not a value of type int
- Specifically for the parseInt(String s, int radix) variant of the function:

  - The second argument radix is either smaller than **Character.MIN_RADIX** or larger than **Character.MAX_RADIX**
    *

> Each character of input string has min and max radix parameter.

- Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign ‘-‘ (‘\u002D’) or plus sign ‘+’ (‘\u002B’) provided that the string is longer than length 1

### Custom logic for conversion

```
String name = "some val";
long key = 0;
for (int i = 0;i<name.length();i++)
    key+= (name.charAt(i) - 'a'+1 ) * Math.pow(26,name.length() - i - 1 );
System.out.println(key);
```

Above code is taken [Converting name to a key using radix-26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58945955/converting-name-to-a-key-using-radix-26)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and do you know how can I do ?

Comment: @Elikill58, Updated answer with code example. Please have a look and let me know if its not correct or you need something else.

Comment: Thanks, this code works. I have a number from the string, but I don't know how to get back the value from it

Comment: Numbers you are multiplying are going out of int storage range and will not return as expected result. I would like to know what is exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to make the string un-readable if you don't use a string. For me, I want to convert to int, multiply by key send/receive it then divide to convert it to string again